# Service Unavailable. Apache2 centos 7

Tags: apache, centos7, php-7.1, http-status-code-503

I have installed apache in centos 7. PHP version 7.1 and php-fpm. I had restarted system. Afterward, apache is working but once i access any file it show me below error.

503 service Unavailable

> Service Unavailable
>
> The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to
>   maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.

Apache log:

> [Tue Nov 13 18:25:25.171750 2018] [proxy:error] [pid 13059]
>   (111)Connection refused: AH00957: FCGI: attempt to connect to
>   127.0.0.1:6000 (127.0.0.1) failed

Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: @larsks [Tue Nov 13 18:25:25.171750 2018] [proxy:error] [pid 13059] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: FCGI: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:6000 (127.0.0.1) failed

Comment: @larsks I mentioned error did you need more information to fix the issue.

Comment: It looks as if it's trying to connect to an FCGI service running on port 6000. Is that service running? That may be your `php-fm` process, although I'm not actually familiar with php.

Comment: Yes, it was running

Answer (score 1):

Finally i got solution of the error. I just uninstall PHP-fpm and used standard PHP 7.1 version and restarted HTTPD services. Its working fine.